# Jagged lines around objects

Tags: 3d-view, image

I have this problem with jagged lines around objects in the 3D-viewport in blender 2.8.
It looks like the problem only occurs on objects in front of the reference images (see picture).

Anyone have the same issue or know how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have "Outline" turned on in the Viewport Shading settings.
[image]